# Can a use case use both extend and include?

Tags: uml, use-case

Can a use case use both extend and include?
For example like the "Take Advanced Knowledge Quest" use case in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Does it make sense in your problem domain?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community the question is about the validity of an UML model and seems specific enough for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In general: of course (when it makes sense, as Robert Harvey commented).

If it makes sense in this specific case is a different question. An "upgrade to premium" may be a precondition of being allowed to "take an advanced knowledge quest", but that does not make the *"upgrading to premium use case"* automatically part of the *"advanced knowledge quest use case"* (at least, that's what I imagine when I read these terse descriptions).